# Bootstrap navbar - removing space between buttons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I have a problem. I have a navbar with links represented by images like in the image below (please ignore the Home link as of now):
[image]

I would like to remove the grey space between each image horizontally. I have tried to set margin: 0% and padding: 0% on all the images and list items, but to no avail. Looking into Bootstraps source code I suspect it has something to do with the navbar-nav and nav classes being flex containers, but what flex property I should give what value to resolve the issue is unclear to me.

Here is the HTML for the navigation bar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_content">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                Survey webapp
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar_content" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#about">
                        <img class="navimage" src="Routine survey.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#contact">
                        <img class="navimage" src="Specific survey.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="navitem">
                    <a href="#help">
                        <img class="navimage" src="Help.png" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="#settings">
                        <img class="navimage" src="Settings.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the relevant (?) CSS:

```css
.nav {
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}

.navbar-nav {
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}

.navitem {
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}
```

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate the help!

Best regards,
Joshua

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if Bootstrap (version 3) applies padding to `<a>` elements inside `.nav`:

```
.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

I don't know if Bootstrap has a native method for removing that padding, but you can always override it yourself:

```
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 0;
}
```